# How to set a wait timeout in Quamotion?

Tags: ios, testing, mobile, webdriver

I'm using Quamotion to test an iOS application. My tests are failing from time to time because it looks like `Find-Element` can't find the element on the screen.

This seems to happen when I switch to a new window and the UI takes some time to load.

Is there any way make `Find-Element` wait for the UI to have loaded completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Set-Timeout`](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/powershell/cmd_set-timeout.html) to set the *implicit wait timeout*. When you use `Find-Element` to find an element, for example `Find-Element -xpath "//*[@name='Login']"`, the Quamotion WebDriver will attempt to find an element that satisfies that XPath expression for the amount of specified by `Set-Timeout`.

You should check whether `Find-Element` returns an actual element ID or not.

If you don't get an element ID, the timeout was hit and the element was not found. Try increasing the timeout.

If you do get an element ID, an element was found but:

- It was not the element you expected. This can happen if you do a [`Find-Element`](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/powershell/cmd_find-element.html) almost immediately after [`Click-Element`](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/powershell/cmd_click-element.html) and the UI structure of the previous page was still in memory;
- Another element matches your XPath expression. You can use [`Get-ElementRectangle`](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/powershell/cmd_get-elementrectangle.html) to get the rectangle of your element and determine whether it's the element you expect or not
- The element has been created in memory but has not been drawn on the screen. You can use [`Is-Displayed`](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/powershell/cmd_is-displayed.html) to determine whether your element has been drawn or not.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this and it looks like `Find-Element` did return an element but the element was not visible. I guess I need to add a wait loop using `Is-Displayed` then?

Comment: Yes, there's no built-in function which will block until an element has bene displayed, so you'll probably need to use `Is-Displayed` in a loop.